# JSON parse data doesn't display in Fragment (using Volley)

Tags: android, json, parsing, fragment, android-volley

I began learning Android development a few months ago and currently I'm learning to work with JSON data.

Few days ago, I've tried to parse JSON data and display it in RecyclerView and it worked (for the whole thing I've followed few Youtube tutorials), but now I want to do the same in Fragment and it doesn't work.

I have a MainActivity, which currently doesn't do anything except navigate through Fragments.

App works (I can navigate), darker gray backgrounds appears when I click on the SensorsFragment button (the one with JSON data), but not the data.

I've tried to found the problem, but I don't see where it is.

This is the data I want to parse: http://www.mocky.io/v2/5cd67f9d300000630060612b

Item class

```
public class SensorItem {

    private String mID;
    private String mType;
    private int mValue;

    public SensorItem(String ID, String Type, int value ){
        mID=ID;
        mType=Type;
        mValue=value;
    }

    public String getID(){
        return mID;
    }

    public String getType(){
        return mType;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return mValue;
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
public class SensorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SensorAdapter.SensorViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<SensorItem> mSensorList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public SensorAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SensorItem> mSensorList){
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mContext=context;
        this.mSensorList=mSensorList;

    }

    @Override
    public SensorViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sensor_item, viewGroup, false);
        SensorViewHolder holder = new SensorViewHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SensorViewHolder holder, int i) {
        SensorItem currentItem = mSensorList.get(i);

        String sensorID = currentItem.getID();
        String sensorType = currentItem.getType();
        int sensorValue = currentItem.getValue();

        holder.mTextViewID.setText(sensorID);
        holder.mTextViewType.setText(sensorType);
        holder.mTextViewValue.setText(sensorValue);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSensorList.size();
    }

    public void clearAdaptor() {
        mSensorList.clear();
    }

    public class SensorViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView mTextViewID;
        public TextView mTextViewType;
        public TextView mTextViewValue;

        public SensorViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextViewID = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
            mTextViewType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_type);
            mTextViewValue = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_value);
        }
    }
}
```

and Fragment

```
public class SensorsFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRyclerView;
    private SensorAdapter mSensorAdapter;
    private ArrayList<SensorItem> mSensorList = new ArrayList<SensorItem>();
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sensors, container, false);

        mRyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mSensorAdapter = new SensorAdapter(getContext(), mSensorList);
        mSensorAdapter.clearAdaptor();

        mRyclerView.setAdapter(mSensorAdapter);
        mRyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        mSensorList = new ArrayList<>();
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        parseJSON();
        return view;
    }

    private void parseJSON(){
        String url = "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5cd67f9d300000630060612b";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("C07-14");

                            for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject sensor = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String ID = sensor.getString("id");
                                String type = sensor.getString("type");
                                int value = sensor.getInt("value");

                                mSensorList.add(new SensorItem(ID, type, value));
                            }

                            mSensorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Also, XML files:

fragment_sensors.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

sensor_item.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:gravity="left"
       >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ID"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TYPE"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_id"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="VALUE"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edit your response

```
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(""+response);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("C07-14");

        for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject sensor = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String ID = sensor.getString("id");
            String type = sensor.getString("type");
            int value = sensor.getInt("value");

            mSensorList.add(new SensorItem(ID, type, value));
        }

        mSensorAdapter.dataChanged(mSensorList);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it's still the same display without the data. I get this: https://imgur.com/a/131DW1e

Comment: i have check i am getting. please log array length

Comment: like JSONArray jsonArray =jsonObject.getJSONArray("C07-14");
            Log.d("arr_len",""+jsonArray.length());

Comment: check i also edit your adapter class and onResponse method of volley

Comment: also add internet permission in AndroidManifest file                                           
               <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: Thank you! Your edited code worked. There was also a problem with "value", I needed to change it from int to String.

Comment: one  more issue you set layout  on recyclerview  later after set adapter on recyclerview, now  i have edit please check